# Python - RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, api, graphql

I'm using Python to request things to the [smashgg API](https://smashgg-developer-portal.netlify.app/docs/intro) (the queries are in GraphQL) and I got an error i never had before while running the code below :

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer my token"}


def run_query(query, variables): # A simple function to use requests.post to make the API call. Note the json= section.
    request = requests.post('https://api.smash.gg/gql/alpha', json={'query': query, 'variables': variables}, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        return request.json()
    else:
        raise Exception("Query failed to run by returning code of {}. {}".format(request.status_code, query))

nbRequestsPerMinute = 75
dataFrameAllSets = pd.read_csv('dataFrameAllSets.csv') #sets of players I already fetched

countryByPlayer = pd.DataFrame(columns = [
    "playerId",
    "playerCountry"
])

uniqueValues1 = dataFrameAllSets["setWinnerId"].unique()
uniqueValues2 = dataFrameAllSets["setLoserId"].unique()
concate = np.concatenate((uniqueValues1, uniqueValues2))
countryByPlayer["playerId"] = concate
countryByPlayer.drop_duplicates(subset = "playerId", inplace = True)
#countryByPlayer has more than 200 000 rows

def queryCountry(playerId) :
    query = """
    query player ($playerId: ID!){
      player(id: $playerId){
        user{
          location {
            country
          }
        }
      }
    }
    """
    variables = {
      "playerId": playerId
    }
    return query, variables

for index, x in countryByPlayer.iterrows() :
    t0 = time.time()
    query, variables = queryCountry(int(x['playerId']))
    result = run_query(query, variables) # Execute the query
    if result["data"]["player"] != None :
        if result["data"]["player"]["user"] != None :
            if result["data"]["player"]["user"]["location"] != None :
                countryByPlayer.at[index, "playerCountry"] = result["data"]["player"]["user"]["location"]["country"]
            else :
                countryByPlayer.at[index, "playerCountry"] = "noneLocation"
    else :
        countryByPlayer.at[index, "playerCountry"] = "nonePlayer"
        
    t1 = time.time()
    if t1 - t0 < 60/nbRequestsPerMinute :
        time.sleep(60/nbRequestsPerMinute - t1 + t0)
```

The error message is the following one :

```
RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
   1320             try:
-> 1321                 response.begin()
   1322             except ConnectionError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
    295         while True:
--> 296             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    297             if status != CONTINUE:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    264             # sending a valid response.
--> 265             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    266                                      " response")

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    366             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 367                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    368             elif read is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
   1320             try:
-> 1321                 response.begin()
   1322             except ConnectionError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
    295         while True:
--> 296             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    297             if status != CONTINUE:

~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    264             # sending a valid response.
--> 265             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    266                                      " response")

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f3b194f946df> in <module>
      4     compteurPlayers += 1
      5     query, variables = queryCountry(int(x['playerId']))
----> 6     result = run_query(query, variables) # Execute the query
      7     if result["data"]["player"] != None :
      8         if result["data"]["player"]["user"] != None :

<ipython-input-2-2a5c0920ef76> in run_query(query, variables)
      3 
      4 def run_query(query, variables): # A simple function to use requests.post to make the API call. Note the json= section.
----> 5     request = requests.post('https://api.smash.gg/gql/alpha', json={'query': query, 'variables': variables}, headers=headers)
      6     if request.status_code == 200:
      7         return request.json()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    114     """
    115 
--> 116     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    117 
    118 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I first thought it had something to do with the rate limit of the API which is set to 80 requests by minutes, however, I delay the loop to always be under this rate limit.
Moreover, when retesting my code multiple times, the error appeared randomly during the loop.

So I come to you guys because I really need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

A remote service is unreliable.

## Solution

Program defensively by handling anticipated errors in your code. Consider implementing an exponential backoff with maximum retries. Also, add logging to track with requests were successful, retried or completely failed. If necessary you may want to implement application monitoring or paging system to alert you if a certain condition is met (100 errors in a row) if this is considered a process critical to your application.

Also, the service may have a bulk API that you can use, so instead of submitting n requests (where n is the number of player ids) you can submit n / bulk_limit (where bulk_limit is the max number of ids their bulk api accepts to process in a single request).